# Fetching a user's profile picture from facebook not working?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here is the code for variable i am using

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  $fbid = $user_profile['id'];                 // To Get Facebook ID
    $fbuname = $user_profile['username'];  // To Get Facebook Username
  if(empty($fbuname))
    $fbuname = $user_profile['name']; // To Get Facebook full name
    $femail = $user_profile['email'];    // To Get Facebook email ID
  checkuser($fbid,$fbuname,$femail,'fb');    // To update local DB
  $_SESSION['userId'] = $fbuname;
```

Here is the code to get image displayed

```
<img class="user_img" src="http://graph.facebook.com/$fbid/picture?type=large">
```

It is not working however. What should i place insted of $fbid in source.

Comment: When you say 'not working' - what's happening?

Comment: A broken image link is showing up?If i substitute a direct value like src="http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=large" picture shows up

Comment: why is a broken image link showing up? Is what's output to the `<img...` tag correct but references a URL that doesn't return an image, or is your code outputting something that is wrong?

Comment: For my pik value of fbid is 1537828979762128 If i substitute it directly link works but if i use src="http://graph.facebook.com/$fbid/picture?type=large"> it does not.

Comment: You need to indicate to the server that the `$fbid` variable is PHP. Try `<img class="user_img" src="http://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $fbid ?>/picture?type=large">`

Comment: As @Igy implies, try to avoid the use of "it is not working". We like to say here that it is the least helpful fault report possible! Whenever you find yourself about to use the phrase, stop, and instead say what you expected, and what you actually got, in detail.

Answer (score 1):

As @halfer said, you're not echoing the `$fbid`variable:

```
<img class="user_img" src="http://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $fbid ?>/picture?type=large">
```

Another thing is that the field `username` no longer exists in the Graph API since v2.0, so it doesn't make sense to query it.